# What is needed to start playing D&D (minimal)

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons

Me and my friends are looking into starting to play D&D. We try to get the minimal necessary books to start whit. I know that the easyest way is to get a red box but its currently out of our price range.

I was looking into the starter kit book -> http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dungeons-Dragons-Starter-Boxed-Game/dp/0786965592/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1402064825&sr=8-1&keywords=dungeons+and+dragons

But i fell like i would need the player guid and monster guide to because they are offen bought in a bundle. Is there a way to get D&D book in digital, except the novels of course.

What is the minimal books we nead to start playing ? Of course we would get more stuff later on. And for the field we would use some home made tokens and re-drawable mat.

We would like to start whit 4.0. Thats the lattest right ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! The product you've linked is the starter set for 5th edition, which comes out this summer. If you'd like to start with 4, the question I've linked as a duplicate will get you started there. If you'd like to start with 5th, please let us know and we can advise there.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. In your oppinion whitch is better for beginers e4 or e5 ? What are the mayoru differences ?

Comment: @Shawn we havent really seen 5e yet. Keep in mind that D&D's "editions" are usually completely different games with a small common legacy. What you want to learn depends on your personal tastes and on those of your fellow players.

Comment: But the play stile stays the same right ? I dont mean all the mechanicks but the styple ? What wersion are u guys playing if i may ask ? 4e or older ?

Comment: 4e is a complicated game to describe. The best description is that its a very refined tactical combat engine with borderline roleplay elements underneath it (not a bad thing, it just relies on more freeform for RP than mechanics). 5e looks to rely less on the tactical combat POV, but we're not sure what the RP elements look like yet. There are copies of the 5e playtest still available online still (drivethru rpg has a couple of adventures that include them), or you could try out 5e when it comes out next month (though not the complete game).

Comment: I think at this point we've exhausted the utility of comments, feel free to pop into chat

Comment: Thank you. I will researche a bit and then come into the chat. But atm i am working :P

Comment: As @Zachiel says, 4e vs. 5e (and the older editions as well) is very much personal opinion. None are objectively "better". If you have a local game store running D&D Encounters, they'll probably have a weekly game you can jump into (most likely 5e), which should help you to make an informed decision without having to pony up the money for several books first.